# Empty a variable without destroying it

Tags: python, variables

I have this piece of code:

```
a = "aa"
b = 1
c = { "b":2 }
d = [3,"c"]
e = (4,5)
letters = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

And I want to do something with it, which will empty them. Without losing their type.

Something like this:

```
>>EmptyVars(letters)
['',0,{},[],()]
```

Any hint?

Comment: After `EmptyVars` runs, do you expect `d` to be `[]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do this:

```
def EmptyVar(lst):
    return [type(i)() for i in lst]
```

`type()` produces the type object for each value, which when called produces an 'empty' new value.

Demo:

```
>>> a = "aa"
>>> b = 1
>>> c = { "b":2 }
>>> d = [3,"c"]
>>> e = (4,5)
>>> letters = [a, b, c, d, e]
>>> def EmptyVar(lst):
...     return [type(i)() for i in lst]
... 
>>> EmptyVar(letters)
['', 0, {}, [], ()]
```

Comment: that was clever..i liked it

Comment: It might be worth noting that to "empty" them isn't quite the same as creating a new instance of the default type... So perhaps other behaviour such as `.clear()` for `MutableMapping` and similar for `MutableSet` and `MutableSequence` compatible types might be appropriate in other circumstances.

Comment: @kame: `type(i)` returns the type object; `int` for an integer, `list` for a list object, etc. Type objects are callable, so `type(i)()` calls the type object which is an empty new object of the same type.

Comment: Therefore type(i)() is like a function?

Comment: Yes; `type()` returns a callable object, which just like functions can be called too. You could instead store the result in a variable too: `foo = type(0)` would store the [`int()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) in `foo`. You could then call `foo()` to produce a new integer `0`.

Comment: @f.rodrigues: `dict.clear()` empties a dictionary; Jon is talking about detecting mutable containers in the input list and clearing them instead of replacing them with an empty value of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Similar way, just `type(i)()` replaced by `i.__class__()`:

```
a = "aa"
b = 1
c = {"b": 2}
d = [3, "c"]
e = (4, 5)

letters = [a, b, c, d, e]


def empty_var(lst):
    return [i.__class__() for i in lst]


print(empty_var(letters))

['', 0, {}, [], ()]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the help of **type()** function which is generally used to display the type of any object or variable in python.
Here is the solution :

```
a = "aa"
b = 1
c = {"b" : 2}
d = [3, "c"]
e = (4,5)
letters = [a,b,c,d,e]
print([type(i)() for i in letters])
```